# Stub setTimeout inside for loop , while testing

Tags: node.js, typescript, jasmine, settimeout, ts-jest

I have this code in node where inside the main function I have for loop for retrying a process and before each retry, I am setting a timeout of 3hrs. And I need to test this main function.

the main function is like this:

```
 export async function main(config: config, logger: logger) {
    //Some code here
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++) {
        await new Promise(resolve => set
Timeout(resolve, i*10800));
        //Some code here
        if(success) {
            return;
}
}
    throw new Error('operation failed');
}
```

the test code is like this :

```
it('unhappy case', async()=>{ 
    //Creating mocks of other necessary functions
    let configFn = jest.fn()// mock of config
    let loggerFn = jest.fn()//mock of logger

    await expect(main(configFn, loggerFn)).rejects.toEqual(new Error('operation failed'))
}
```

I am running a test and getting an error
`async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout. async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error`

How can I mock this setTimeout or fake this timeout function to let the test run without waiting for that amount of time? And just fail after running through the loop without waiting?

I am expecting the test to run through the main function and for loop but not wait for the specified timeout before retrying while testing.

If using a wrapper function for delay like :

```
export async function delay(ms: number) {
    await new Promise (resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

How do I mock this in test so that, when this is being called from test it gets some value like 1sec that I can set from test code itself.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks

Comment: You can write a wrapper function for setTimeout, which accepts timeout as parameter. This way you can pass arbitrary timeout and run it with in jest timeout of 5sec

Comment: @AbhishekChandel i tried with a wrapper function for setTimeout, but I'm not sure how to pass that arbitrary value to the wrapper function while testing. So that when that wrapper is called from within main it gets only arbitrary value and not that 3hr value.

Answer (score 0):

change your main function to accept delay like this:

```
export async function main(config: config, logger: logger, delay = 10800) {
    //Some code here
  for(let i=0; i<3; i++) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, i * delay));
    //Some code here
    if(success) {
      return;
    }
  }
  throw new Error('operation failed');
}
```

Then your test will look like

```
it('unhappy case', async()=>{ 
    //Creating mocks of other necessary functions
    let configFn = jest.fn()// mock of config
    let loggerFn = jest.fn()//mock of logger

    await expect(main(configFn, loggerFn, 3000)).rejects.toEqual(new Error('operation failed'))
}
```

If this is something you cannot do, you make your delay configurable by getting it from env vars.